# Is there anyway to connect to Azure SQL Server using jTDS with TLS 1.2?

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, jtds, azure-sql-managed-instance

Our Java app use jTDS 1.3.1 to connect to SQL Server, which works fine until a client trying to put the database on Azure SQL. The connection failed with the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Reason: Login failed due to client TLS version being less than minimal TLS version allowed by the server.

I checked the documentation of jTDS, can't see anyway to specify TLS version. Besides replacing it with MS JDBC driver, has anyone succeeded with other work around?

I don't have access to Azure SQL, so I cannot test if reducing the TLS version to 1.0 would work.

Answer (score 6):

Had this same issue when trying to connect a .Net application to a Azure SQL database in Azure managed instance.

Here's how I solved it.

My previous JDBC URL was this:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://my-example-instance.c656df8582985.database.windows.net:1433
```

I just added `ssl=require` to the end of the URL, so it became:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://my-example-instance.c656df8582985.database.windows.net:1433;ssl=require
```

Answer (score 5):

Solved the issue by chance. Just need to append ";ssl=request" to the connection string. It looks like by default SSL/TLS is disabled. The error message about TLS version is misleading. Hope this help someone in the future.

Comment: Appending ";ssl=request" to the Hostname field also fixed this issue for me in SQL Developer.