# Oracle SQL-Developer doesn't connect to SQL Server in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, oracle-sqldeveloper, multi-factor-authentication

I want to connect an SQL Server Database hosted in Azure configured with MFS from Oracle SQL-Developer.

Currently I am able to connect to this db server using SSMS just by putting the Server Name, user name & password, Default Network Protocol and choosing the Authentication type as 'Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA.

But when using SQL-Developer it asks for Http/Https, Hostname, Port, Server Path & Service Name where I don't know what should be entered.

I tried by only entering the URL (the server Name I use is SSMS), but it failed to connect.

Do anyone know how I can make the connection successful?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I doubt Sql Developer supports AAD auth, especially not MFA which uses a browser popup.  If not you'll have to use SQL Server Auth.

Answer (score 0):

To access the Azure SQL database in the Oracle SQL developer tool, you must download the **JTDC driver** which will be useful to connect to third party database.

I am able to make the **successful connection** from SQL developer tool to Azure SQL database by following below procedure:

- Download the latest JTDC jar file from the URL below: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/
- Upload the jar file in the below path: *Tools>>preferences>>Database>>Third Party JDBC driver*
  [image]
- After that, trigger the **new connection** from the developer tool and then you can get option to select SQL server
  [image]
- Give the connection name, credentials and host name to access the database.
  [image]

From **SSMS**:

[image]

**From SQL Developer tool:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Sourav, I had tried this but I had to use the user name as myemail@MyServerURL as I use Azure AD login(my email is my user name) and SQL Developer takes the text after @ as the server url. 
I appended ;ssl=request (ssl=require  as well) along with my server url in the hostname field because without that I was getting the error mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67310070/is-there-anyway-to-connect-to-azure-sql-server-using-jtds-with-tls-1-2. But even after this I am getting Login Failed error message.

Comment: Please raise this concern on [MS Q&A] (docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) or reach out to Microsoft support.