# How can i debug Anylogic SQL database TLS error?

Tags: database, anylogic

I want to connect my SQL database to Anylogic to conduct some experiments. Even if I can reach my database via python and SQL Management Stuido (that means i can reach from other softwares), I cannot connect Anylogic. It gives me this error: Login failed due to client TLS version being less than minimal TLS version allowed by the server. In addition, my database's TLS version is 1.2 and I know that Anylogic released 1.3 in last April. To intersect their versions I even tried to write my mail file's simulation window> Advanced Java> Java Machine Arguments gap:
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2. However it still gave me the same error. How can i fix this?
Thanks in advance.

#Anylogic

In addition, my database's TLs version is 1.2 and I know that Anylogic released 1.3 in last April. To intersect their versions I even tried to write my mail file's simulation window> Advanced Java> Java Machine Arguments gap:
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2. However it still gave me the same error. How can i fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect using the JDBC Driver and add `ssl=require` to the connection URL as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67310070/is-there-anyway-to-connect-to-azure-sql-server-using-jtds-with-tls-1-2).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, Benjamin. I  successfully connected to the database. I have one more question. After I connected to the MS Azure Database, I couldn't see the table I only used and built. 4 table shown which I have never seen before : dbo_sysdac_history_internal, dbo_sysdac_instances_internal, sys_trace_xe_action_map, sys_trace_xe_event_map . How can I reach my table directly and why my table was not shown? Thank you.

Comment: Hey, glad it helped. Pls always open new issues for new questions, though, SOF does not work like a forum :)

Comment: I asked as an additional issue :) Thank you